# Create a circle array of angles to not consider euclidean distance python

Tags: python, numpy, angle

I am trying to create a transition matric using this code:

```
transition_matrix[0:720,:] = (1 / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * sigma_n2)) * np.exp(-( np.abs(eventspace_psi_i_min_1 - eventspace_psi_i) )**2 / (2 * sigma_n2))
```

where the formula after it is just the Gaussian distribution.

The eventspaces are arrays of 720 elements, all of which are supposed to angles starting from 0,0.5,...,359.5.
Knowing how close 0° and 359.5° are, a non-zero value should appear in the transition matrix for this calculation. But, because of Eucidean distance, it returns 0.

I tried switching up the eventspaces and making them: 0, 0.5,...,180,179.5,...,0,5 but it doesn't work because again of Eukidean distance, since it will give a non-zero when considering 90° and the equivalent for 270° (which is 90 in this case).

In order for this to perform properly, I need to have the angle values in a circle as they would usually appear in a diagram.

Can anyone help me understand how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit puzzled because you're using degrees, not radians, however if you want an angular distance with the property `0 ≤ δ ≤ 180` you can go like this

```
def distance(φ, θ):
    from numpy import abs
    δ = abs(φ-θ)         #    0 ≤ δ < 360
    δ[δ>=180] -= 360     # -180 ≤ δ < 180
    return abs(δ)        #    0 ≤ δ ≤ 180
```

*edit*

Your angles are in the [0, 360) interval, but this is not always the case, so it's better to normalize them, moreover if the arguments are both scalars a `TypeError` is raised, so it's better to envelope the 360 decrement into a `try` `except` clause.

```
def distance(φ, θ):
    from numpy import abs
    δ = abs(φ%360 - θ%360)  #    0 ≤ δ < 360
    try:
        δ[δ>=180] -= 360    # -180 ≤ δ < 180
    except TypeError:
        if δ >= 180 : δ -= 360
   return abs(δ)            #    0 ≤ δ ≤ 180
```

Comment: It works if φ and θ are Numpy arrays, it does not work if they are scalars.  Please see my incoming edit...